# When creating a class object, I get "error: linker command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: c++

When ever I attempt to create a dgraph object, I get a compile error but I can link and compile the files perfectly fine when I omit the line that creates the dgraph object. Please help! Thanks.

This is main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"dgraph.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string test;
  test = "Hello, world!";
  cout << test << endl;
  slist L1;
  L1.displayAll();
  dgraph L2; //offending line
  return 0;
}
```

This is my dgraph.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "slist.h"

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 20;
struct Gvertex
{
  char vertexName;      //the vertex Name
  int outDegree;    //the Out degree
  slist adjacentOnes;   //the adjecent vertices in an slist
  int visit;            // This will hold the visit number in HW7 
};

class dgraph
{

private:
  Gvertex Gtable[SIZE];  // a table representing a dgraph
  int  countUsed; // how many slots of the Gtable are actually used

public:

  class BadVertex {};  // thrown when the vertex is not in the graph

  dgraph();
  ~dgraph();
  void fillTable();  
  void displayGraph(); 
  int findOutDegree(char);  
  slist findAdjacency(char);  
};
```

dgraph.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include"dgraph.h"

void dgraph::fillTable()
{
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("table.txt");
  while(fin >> Gtable[countUsed].vertexName) //if you can read the name
  {
    char x; //temp var
    fin >> Gtable[countUsed].outDegree;
    for (int i = 0; i < Gtable[countUsed].outDegree; ++i)
    {
      fin >> x;
      Gtable[countUsed].adjacentOnes.addRear(x);
    }
    countUsed++;
  }
  fin.close();
}
```

I am compiling using g++ -c then using g++ -o to link all the files together. 
Here is the exact error I get when I compile:

```
g++ -o run hw6Client.o dgraph.o llist.o slist.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"dgraph::~dgraph()", referenced from:
  _main in hw6Client.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

Comment: What about dgraph.cpp?

Comment: Ok I updated the original post with dgraph.cpp.

Comment: `dgraph.cpp` is missing the implementations of most of the member functions.

Comment: Thanks, I tried compiling without those member functions and I'm still getting an error.

Comment: Unrelated: If `slist` is what it reads like, a singly linked list, consider replacing it with a `std::vector`. Lighter in weight and almost certainly much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The header declares the dgraph object, but doesn't define the implementation. This is no problem as long as you don't actually create a dgraph object. The problem comes when you include the offending line which actually declares a dgraph object. When you do this, the linker will look for the actual implementation somewhere, but can't find it. You need to include the implementation of

```
void dgraph::filltable()
void dgraph::displayGraph()
int dgraph::findOutDegree(char) 
slist dgraph::findAdjacency(char)
dgraph::dgraph()
dgraph::~dgraph()
```

somewhere where the linker will find it. You need to explicitly define the constructor and destructor because you explicitly declared them.

Comment: Addendum: [The Rule of Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) suggests this code most likely doesn't need the destructor.

Comment: I omitted the all of the member functions besides the constructor and fillTable function and I am still getting the compiling error.

Comment: Did you implement the constructor? `dgraph::dgraph(): countUsed(0) {}` or something similar.

Comment: Did you explicitly define the constructor though? You can either define a constructor, or omit the declaration, and it should compile.

Comment: I implemented the constructor and still receiving the same error. I even tried the above example, dgraph::dgraph(): countUsed(0) {}.

Comment: Do you still have the destructor in the header file? If so, get rid of it